# Translating SAS to SPSS: Using temporary (IN= ) variables to code a permanent variable

Tags: merge, sas, spss, translate, temporary

When I merge datasets in SAS I often program in a variable to indicate whether or not each record was in each source dataset.
For example:

```
data test_match;
merge rx (in=x) enc (in=y);
by pid;
if x=1 then In_Rx=1; else In_Rx=0;
if y=1 then In_Enc=1; else In_Enc=0;
run;
```

Does SPSS allow for a similar action? The workaround which I use is to program in the "In_" indicator variable in the original source dataset before merging, but I would like to move it to the MATCH command if that is feasible.
Thank you